# using different serializer for the same model appearing at different places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

hope someone can help me on this

I am using the rails serializers to format my model output to a RESTFul JSON web service.

Now my question is...

Say if I have a model user, that I will be using everywhere amongst the application.  Some of the places I want pretty much all the user data (name, email, phone, addresses...etc.), while others I just want the name, email.  However, these user objects are attachment to some main model via has_many, belongs_to...etc.

So how could I indicate which serializer I want for users at each specific output.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you want custom serializer each case, so use different serializers.

```
 has_many :users, serializer: UserAllSerializer
```

Also this in case you want to remove the entire key, from [the github page of rails serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#customizing-scope).

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body
  has_many :comments

  def filter(keys)
    keys.delete :comments if object.comments_disabled?
    keys
  end
end
```

If you want to scope your serialization, take a look [at this part](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#customizing-scope)